# How to search all sheet names for values (partial matches)

Tags: excel, vba, each, inputbox

I have a workbook with multiple sheets in a master roster book which are named based on a roster cycle number.

Each roster cycle will have varying named sheets with a common number to designate the Roster Cycle eg: "322", "R 322", "OT 322 - WE32".

I am looking for a way to search all my sheets with VBA with an input box to find and select all sheets with the common string ("322" in this case).

I've compiled some code to just find the sheets however i am running into a runtime error 13 when the code gets to the Next ws line.

Is there something I am missing?

```
Public Sub FindSheets()
    Dim RosterCycle As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    RosterCycle = Application.InputBox("Enter Roster Cycle")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       If ws.Name Like "*" & RosterCycle & "*" Then ws.Select
       found = True
     Next ws 'Generates RuntimeError 13
End Sub
```

Comment: If the sheets are in the workbook containing this code, replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`. The error is probably occurring because you are using a worksheet variable to loop through the `Sheets` collection which also includes charts. Either use a variable to accommodate both (`Dim sh As Object`) or loop through the `Worksheets` collection (`... In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`). `found = True` will result in `found` always being `True` because you wrote it outside the If statement and you never reset it. BTW, use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module (`found` is not declared).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have forgotten an `End If`, something like:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   If ws.Name Like "*" & RosterCycle & "*" Then
     ws.Select
     found = True
   End If
 Next ws
```